# iteration, JSON and callback in JS

Tags: javascript, json, callback, jsonp, yql

**(translation with Google Traductor)**
Hi, I'm learning javascript, and I was trying to simulate the change that occurs in the stock quotes on page yahoo finance.

I was reading many responses from stackoverflow page, and I did this.

http://js.do/code/53880
If you are using google chrome, after about a minute into the console errors occur. 
Control -Shift -J  (console tab/ error)

error:
net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCESjquery-1.9.1.js:8336 sendjquery-1.9.1.js:7978 jQuery.extend.ajaxVM8678:12 update

also the page is lags

```js
$(function(){
$(function() {
 setInterval(update, 0);
});


function update() {
 var query = "select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol = ";
 var symbolo = "'AAPL'"; 
 var yql = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + escape(query+symbolo) + "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=?";
 var xhr2 = $.ajax({ 
  url: yql,
  jsonp: "myCallback",
  dataType: 'jsonp', 
  success: function(data) {
   var keys = data.query.results.quote;
   $("#a").html(keys.LastTradePriceOnly);   
  }, 
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   alert("oth1"+xhr.statusText); 
   alert("oth2"+xhr.responseText); 
   alert("oth3"+xhr.status); 
   alert("oth4"+thrownError);
  }
 });
} 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(update, 0);
```

You keep spawning Ajax requests as fast as possible. Then you run out of resources (probably before the first request has been handled).

Run the `update` function *once*, and then call it again (preferably with a `setTimeout` based delay) from inside the `success` and `error` function.

Comment: Consider whether it really needs to run as fast as possible. a `setTimeout` inside the `success` or `error` handlers would likely help.